# Iteration through a range of timestamp in Python

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a dataframe df :

```
TIMESTAMP equipement1 equipement2
2016-05-10 13:20:00 0.000000 0.000000
2016-05-10 14:40:00 0.400000 0.500000
2016-05-10 15:20:00 0.500000 0.500000
```

Iam trying to iterate through timestamp by step of 5 minutes .
I try : `pd.date_range(start, end, freq='5 minutes')`

But I get a problem with timestamp format.

> " ValueError: Could not evaluate 5 minutes"

Any idea to help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: from `pd` I am guessing you are using pandas library.  You should add that tag.

Comment: I get this error : " ValueError: Could not evaluate 5 minutes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure your TIMESTAMP column is a datetime instead of a string (e.g. `df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP)`).

Next, use this column as the index of the dataframe.  To make this permanent, `df.set_index('TIMESTAMP`, inplace=True)`.

Now you can [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) for any given frequency (e.g. `30min`) and use different methods of aggregation such as `sum`, `mean` (the default), a lambda function, etc).

Optionally, you can add `.fillna(0)` to replace the NaNs with zeros.

```
>>> df.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample('30min', how='sum')

                     equipement1  equipement2
TIMESTAMP                                    
2016-05-10 13:00:00          0.0          0.0
2016-05-10 13:30:00          NaN          NaN
2016-05-10 14:00:00          NaN          NaN
2016-05-10 14:30:00          0.4          0.5
2016-05-10 15:00:00          0.5          0.5
```

Comment: thank you, in case of lambda fucntion , i make how='lambda' and then   I create a fucnction lambda def lambda? Is it ?  thank you

Comment: `df.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample('30min', how=lambda group: group.sum())`